# refactoring code that contains "button addTarget"

Tags: ios, refactoring

I have a lot of places of a code that changes a view in UINavigationBar.
So the code is something like this:

```
UIButton *butt2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];

[butt2 setFrame:CGRectMake(285, 7, 30, 25)];
[butt2 setTag:2];
[butt2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tag_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[butt2 addTarget:self action:@selector(revealMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:butt2] ;
```

I want to create a method that gets argument of the different things in the code which is:
1. the image (easy)
2. The action of the button - **AHA! This one I couldn't figure out how to do**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will decide to implement it as function it could be something like

```
void addNavigationButton(UIViewController *vc, UIImage *image, SEL action)
{
    UIButton *butt2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];

    [butt2 setFrame:CGRectMake(285, 7, 30, 25)];
    [butt2 setTag:2];
    [butt2 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [butt2 addTarget:vc action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [vc.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:butt2] ;
}
```

It should be called in your view controller

```
addNavigationButton(self, [UIImage imageNamed:@"tag_icon.png"], @selector(revealMenu:));
```

Another good idea - implement this function as a UIViewController's category method.

Answer (score 0):

Add target prototype is:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

If you use the same type "SEL" you should pass @selector(yourMethod) to your method.

Comment: and what about the event? how do I pass it as an argumet?

Comment: The event is a UIControlEvents type which is basically a typedef NS_OPTIONS there should be no problem with it. But honestly I don't really see what you try to do by refactoring this method.